# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, error calling extend from inherited list class

Tags: python, inheritance

I wrote the following code,

```
    #sanitize fuction
def sanitize(time_string):
   if '-' in time_string:
      splitter = '-'
   elif ':' in time_string:
      splitter = ':'
   else:
      return(time_string)
   (mins, secs) = time_string.split(splitter)
   return(mins + '.' + secs)

class AthleteList(list):
   def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_times=[]):
      list.__init__([])
      self.name = a_name
      self.dob = a_dob
      self.extend = a_times
   def top3(self):
      return(sorted(set([sanitize(t) for t in self]))[0:3])

#get coach data fuction
def get_coach_data(filename):
   try:
      with open(filename) as f:
         data = f.readline()
         templ = data.strip().split(',')
         return(AthleteList(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ))
   except IOError as ioerr:
      print('File error: ' + str(ioerr))
      return(None)

sarah = get_coach_data("sarah2.txt")
julie = get_coach_data("julie2.txt")
james = get_coach_data("james2.txt")
mikey= get_coach_data("mikey2.txt")

vera = AthleteList('vera')
vera.append('1.33')
vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
print(vera.top3())
```

When I run this code, it shows the following error.
**But it only shows error when I use extend method.**
  I can use append method with no probs.

> vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
>
> > TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You overwrote `extend` in `__init__`. It's not a method anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically trying to call a list (`self.extend = a_times` and `a_times = []`), which is impossible.

What you'd need to do, is use:

```
vera.extend.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
```

Or either this (as mentioned before):

```
vera.extend = ['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40']
```

But actually this is not exactly correct either (given we need `vera` list and not `vera.extend` one [missed this when first posted, sorry!]), as shown here:

```
>>> vera = AthleteList("vera")
>>> vera.extend = ['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40']
>>> print(vera.top3())
[]
>>> vera.extend.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
>>> print(vera.top3())
[]
```

The correct answer would be remove self.extend from AthleteList class so it works the way you want it (`vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])`).

```
>>> vera = AthleteList("vera")
>>> vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
>>> print(vera.top3())
['1.40', '1.42', '1.46']
```

So, class should be like this:

```
class AthleteList(list):
   def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_times=[]):
      list.__init__([])
      self.name = a_name
      self.dob = a_dob
   def top3(self):
      return(sorted(set([sanitize(t) for t in self]))[0:3])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To Access list you need to use  the square brackets ([]) and not the parenthesis (()).

instead of

```
vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])
```

use

```
  aList = ['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40']
   vera.extend(aList)
```

Comment: This statement `vera.extend['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40']` seems to have no effect, kindly update your reference, if any

Answer (score 1):

Follow the execution path from `AthleteList('vera')`, noting how `self.extend` gets initialized to a list, which shadows the function you expect.

what's happening is essentially this:

```
>>> extend = []
>>> extend(['foo'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you have initialized a class variable extend to an empt list.

```
self.extend = a_times
```

where `a_times = []`

It is a **variable**, **not a function** according to your code. That is why it is throwing an error of '*not callable*'

Change the following line of code:

`vera.extend(['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40'])` to `vera.extend = ['1.74','1.46','1.42','1.40']`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the definition of `class AtheleteList`

`self.extend = a_times` should be change to `self.extend(a_times)`